# search an user input throughout an article

Tags: python, for-loop

For some reason, I can't return how many times an user input appears in an article.  Here is my code

```
infile = open ("the path to the file...blah blah")
count = 0 
for line in infile:
    user = input("please enter a search term or click x to exist: " )
    if user in line:
        count = count + 1   
        print("your input appears",count "times")
else:
    print("invalid")

infile.close()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Try putting a comma after `count` in your print statement.  Should `user` be defined outside the loop?

Comment: here is the error:                                                                                     please enter a search term or click x to exist: America
invalid
please enter a search term or click x to exist:

Answer (score 0):

Your above program is wrong for a number of reasons. First, as it was mentioned in the comments, you have to have a comma after `count` in print or make it `str(count)` and add to the string when printing. Also logically your program is wrong as your count variable is appended only once before printing the output per line. What you need is to print it after the total count is taken.

Try this simple solution.

```
infile = open ("your_file")
count = 0
lines = infile.readlines()
lines = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]
user = input("please enter a search term or click x to exist: " )

for line in lines:
    if user in line:
        count += line.count(user)

print("your input appears " + str(count) + " times")

infile.close()
```

This should work for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It works now.  However, I would still like to know what does the following code mean?    lines = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]    And why it's "count += line.count(user)" not "count += count +1"

Comment: When the file is first read in to the lines variable, it becomes a list with each line of the file as its elements. Entire sentence becomes an element. What `lines = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]` does is, it iterates through each of the read lines and it strips the white space characters from the line ends and splits each sentence into a list of words and replaces the original sentence in the lines list with this newly created words list. 

What `count += line.count(user)` does is, it counts how many times a given word appears on each of these word lists and adds to the total.